# sum time from datetimepicker into textbox

Tags: c#

in `c#` in a windows form I have five timepicker only time format.
The four values are written on 4 textbox.
I need in a fifth `textbox` or `timepicker`, to view the sum of hours of pprecedenti 4.

this code is wrong:

```
TimeSpan result = this.dateTimePicker22.Value + this.dateTimePicker23.Value + this.dateTimePicker24.Value + this.dateTimePicker25.Value + this.dateTimePicker26.Value);
this.textBox21.Text = result.ToString();
```

I calculate work hours so:

```
    private void Calcolaweek1()
    {
        textBox23.MaxLength = 5;
        DeleteChars();
        if (textBox23.Text.Length == 2)
            textBox23.Text += ":";

        textBox23.SelectionStart = textBox23.Text.Length;

        DateTime time = new DateTime();
        this.textBox23.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm");


        if ((textBox1.Text.Length > 0) && (textBox2.Text.Length > 0) && (textBox3.Text.Length > 0) && (textBox4.Text.Length > 0))
        {
            textBox23.MaxLength = 5;
            TimeSpan result = this.dateTimePicker4.Value - this.dateTimePicker1.Value - (this.dateTimePicker3.Value - this.dateTimePicker2.Value);
            this.textBox23.Text = result.ToString();

        }
        else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text)))
        {

            TimeSpan result1 = this.dateTimePicker4.Value - this.dateTimePicker1.Value;
            this.textBox23.Text = result1.ToString();
        }

    }
```

I must sum all work hours day

Comment: why you are using ++

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. I use only "+"

Comment: what is the exception you have got ?

Comment: And what's the point of adding times? what would you expect if you sum `12:00:00` and `23:59:00`?

Comment: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type system.datetime

Comment: @aricbetta So edit your question and replace the `++` with `+` because  as it's currently written is misleading!

Comment: I must sum time that i imposed from windows form into timepicker.i want to sum This four time that i imposed

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: Be calm while coding ..  I think you need to read this before you start https://medium.com/@darthpanda/calm-down-anxious-programmer-e16720782a34#.85bq1kdi1

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 you are right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      int hours = picker1.Value.Hour % 12 +
                  picker2.Value.Hour % 12 +
                  picker3.Value.Hour % 12 +
                  picker4.Value.Hour % 12 +
                  picker5.Value.Hour % 12;

      int minutes = picker1.Value.Minute % 60 +
                    picker2.Value.Minute % 60 +
                    picker3.Value.Minute % 60 +
                    picker4.Value.Minute % 60 +
                    picker5.Value.Minute % 60;

      TimeSpan fromMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
      var ts = hours + fromMinutes.Hours + ":" + fromMinutes.Minutes;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I have hours and minute? HH:mm

Comment: what do you mean by **HH:mm** @aricbetta? In your question you said that you want to add Hours and Minutes and **DateTimePicker** control have these properties in my answer .Hour is your HH and .Minute is your mm. What else you need to know?

Comment: i have in five datetimepicker "07:38:00" and i want to obtain "38:10:00".

Comment: you mean to say that you've fifth datetimepicker and you want to calculate the sum **(206)**  and show it in HH:mm format. Am I right?

Comment: yes!! correctly. But in format HH:mm. look at https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXtp7.png

Comment: Your code it's ok but i don't have the exactly hours and minute. I would obtain 38:10 if i have 07:38 in five textbox or datetimepicker

Comment: check now @aricbetta

Comment: i have write at last "textBox21.Text=ts;". 
i have 07:38:00 in other timepickers and your code returns sum=10:5